# How to automatically reload a python file when it is changed

Tags: python

If I make some changes to one of the files belonging to a running app, is there a way to tell the python runtime to automatically reload the module/file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take at look at [CherryPy's Autoreload feature](http://www.cherrypy.org/attachment/wiki/AutoReload/autoreload.py). I think it looks quite simple and always worked well for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very old module that I posted nearly ten years ago.  I may no longer work with current Python versions (I have not checked) but it may give some ideas.

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-April/031568.html

Comment: ...and the highest voted answer since the Django module started with CherryPy.

Comment: Hey, I didn't even know that.

Answer (score 4):

Take look at [Django's autoreload module](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/utils/autoreload.py). It works very well.